# Define a star "*" - to become a dot

Tags: math-mode, symbols

When writing in mathmode, is it possible to define a * to become \cdot, in the main document?

As it makes it easier when writing equations to make a star.

Comment: Just hope you don't need any star macros in math mode...Just sayin'

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes `\star` will do, in that case.

Answer (score 34):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

% \DeclareMathSymbol{\cdot}{\mathbin}{symbols}{"01} % from fontmath.ltx
\DeclareMathSymbol{*}{\mathbin}{symbols}{"01}
\begin{document}

$ x * y $

\end{document}
```

Comment: Donald just beat me to it by a second or two , but mine's a bit more latex-y and comes with a picture, so I posted anyway.

Comment: how about  textmode  for example define  `.` to appears  as `-` ?

Comment: @SalimBou you want to make every full stop a dash???? That is a lot harder if you want to not break uses such as `width=0.5\textwidth`

Comment: This is just an example my question is how to do the same in textmode not exactly with dot but with any other char.

Comment: Define `?` to appears as `!` for example.

Comment: @SalimBou classic tex has no corresponding feature for text mode. You can make the character active and give it a definition, just as `~` is `\nobreakspace` but for example if you made `*` active to make it . in text mode, all `*` forms of commands like `\section*` would break unless you changed them to match, which would then break many packages handling section headings... so for `?`  `\catcode\`?\active \def?{!}`  but things will break.

Comment: This does not work for fonts other than the default, right? Then you need Donald's solution.

Comment: @Gooz well there I used `{symbols}{"01}` so will use whatever font is set up as the symbol font, doesn't have to be computer modern. If you have declared an additional font and you want to use that just reference that instead of `symbols`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle thanks. I found out that for libertinust1math you must use `0C` instead of `01`.

Comment: @Gooz the intention of the commented line here was to indicate that you should look up the font and slot used for `\cdot` in the font package being used and use the same values for `*` so if it's `0C` then that is what it is.

Answer (score 18):

Either

```
\mathcode`\*=\number\cdot
```

or

```
\mathcode`\*=\number\circ
```

or

```
\mathcode`\*=\number\bullet
```

(The `\number` isn't really necessary, but it might help for abnormal versions of `\circ` or `\cdot` or `\bullet`.)

Comment: If a class or package defines `\cdot` to be `\mathbin{foo}`, using `\number` would do nothing good. I'm not sure what “abnormal” definition you're thinking to.

Comment: Mainly hoping that the context displayed in the error message would be clearer.

Answer (score 9):

As I pointed out in a comment, redefining the use of `*` ***in the wrong way*** will prevent you from using star versions of math-mode macros (see partial list below*).  For example, making `*` active would be the wrong way.  However, David C and Don both note that their approaches do not suffer this problem, and I was negligent for not noting the distinction.

While the use of star macros in math mode may be rare, it occurs often enough to warrant avoiding an approach that would use an active `*`.  Even if you use David's approach, you lose the use of the typeset asterisk in math mode, unless you save it beforehand into a named macro.

An alternative that does not mess with `*` in any way would be to redefine `\*`.  This is a plain-Tex macro known as a "discretionary multiplication sign".  I've never used it myself, but the idea is that you can place it between multiplied math terms.  Normally, it does nothing, but if the line breaking wants to happen between the two terms, a symbol (equivalent to `\times`) is inserted at the line end (in text size).  It acts like a mathematical hyphen, but with `\times` instead of `-`.  If you, like me, never use such a construct, then I think it would be safer to redefine `\*` rather than `*`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\renewcommand\*{\cdot}
\begin{document}
$ x \* y $
\end{document}
```

[image]

*Examples of star macros include things like `\tag*`, `\ref*`, `\\*`, `\matrix*` (and all its variants), `\operatorname*`, `\alignat*`, just to get started.

Comment: the definition I gave in my answer would not affect `*` forms in math mode, so I am not sure I follow your first sentence?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks for pointing that out.  I will revise my answer.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Please check to see if I have mischaracterized the situation, upon EDIT. I apologize for the prior omission.

Comment: :-)............

Comment: None of the other answers "redefine" the `*` character; they do not change how * is interpreted in text or in syntactical contexts.

Comment: My apologies, @DonaldArseneau .  I did not mean, through my own ignorance, to disparage any of the other answers.

Comment: Don't worry @StevenB.Segletes, no disparagement taken; I was just hoping to clarify, too tersely though. I see the wording is different, so I was probably just misunderstanding your intended statement.

Answer (score 5):

For the sake of completness, version for `unicode-math`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\AtBeginDocument{\Umathcode`\* = 2 0 "22C5}
\begin{document}
$x*y$
\end{document}
```